# Create kafka message with CRC

Tags: apache-kafka

For testing I want to purposely create a kafka message with a bad CRC to ensure I have the proper logic for handling this scenario (happens every so often in our production env, and right now it causes the partition to backup until a human intervenes). Using the Java debugger I can override the CRC from Compressor.computeChecksum() to simulate the scenario. I have also had success with manually editing the .log files and restarting kafka servers to create a message with bad CRC.

However neither of these are great for doing automated tests, nor are they applicable to our QA envs. Ideally I'd like to have a tool I can run that produces bad messages. The problem I am having is that the kafka servers always reject any message with a bad CRC. I have tried both the Java and Perl clients (modifying the code to not properly calculate the CRC), and the server always reject them.

Anyone know of technique I can use for this? Or an existing tool that might help?

Comment: Have you first tried to investigate about the reasons of this failure/CRC error?

Comment: More time than I care to admit :) We don't totally understand why this happens, the only correlation we have is that it's related to periods of extremely high message traffic and/or times when one or more kafka brokers experience problems. Since we cannot readily reproduce the problem, we would like to have some defensive code around it to at least prevent the partition(s) from starting to lag.

Comment: It might be a tuning issue. Have you tried to follow some guides like http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-kafka/latest/topics/kafka_performance.html?